# Ethers.js function createRandom() is too slow when generating private-public key pair

Tags: ethers.js

I am trying to generate a wallet/private_key inside my app. However, it often takes 25-30 seconds to get a result.

```
    const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();  //Takes 1 second
    const signer = ethers.Wallet.createRandom().connect(provider);  //Takes 30 seconds !!!

    await this.context.contextFunctions.saveNewAccount(
                signer.address,
                signer._signingKey().privateKey,
                0,
              );
```

What I am looking for is a faster way of generating a Private_key and Address. (Generating a wallet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the createRandom() function is too slow because it is also creating a mnemonic of the private key. The solution was to create my own "createRandom()" function that doesn't contain that step.